# Changing RoR Environment or disable authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx

I am dealing with a Ruby on Rails website that is currently being rebuilt into PHP. General information then the questions.

- Ubuntu 14 server running RoR with Nginx.
- Four sites, 2 of which are staging and 2 are production, for 2 different clients. Each site is contained within it's own directory.
- The dev that set these up also used Capistrano.
- I have SSH access, but no access to git, so cannot bundle, if that is needed.
- One of the clients parks the primary domain during low season and activates it before peak. It is the production version of this clients site this is about.

Questions:
1. The production version is apparently not running. Using ps auxf, I can see the other 3 RoR sites, not the production one that is desired for the client to point to. How does one go about turning on a site with Passenger RubyApp?
2. If I can't turn on the production site, I am content with using the staging version that is running, since it is a temporary fix. Staging however has authentication enabled within the staging.rb file. So this question is, how can I disable the authentication OR set the environment to production? Both staging and production rb files are located in site directories.

Sample Authentication:

```
# HTTP auth
    config.middleware.use '::Rack::Auth::Basic' do |u, p|
        [u, p] == ['test-user', 'auth']
    end
```

My goal is to have a working site for them, which will run for 2 weeks before we move them over to the new built PHP site.

Comment: It sounds like you should probably just hire a rails and/or a sys admin contractor...

Comment: I mean.. the fact that you *don't have access to git* is very scary! Why don't you have access, if you've been in charge of this project for 6 months? Are you re-writing this in PHP with no MVC framework or source control??!!

Comment: Your question could be summarised in one sentence: *"How do I restart, or reconfigure, my application"*? With the information you have provided, I can only guess. `bundle exec passenger start`?? I'd really need to log on to the server to see how it's all been configured. It's you who is being paid to solve this problem, not me.

Comment: ...Or more likely, the previous developer wrote a capistrano task to automate this stuff. Try running `cap -T` on your machine, and see what tasks are defined.

Comment: Thank you for the cap -T option, but Capistrano apparently isn't installed on the server, since I tried it. I appreciate the educated guesses. I have not asked anyone to solve this, I have asked for potential solutions to a problem. Strictly speaking, I am not being paid to solve it either, so again, options to try are worthwhile. Comments as to how potentially screwed we are are irrelevant, as I know those things better than you. As for "bundle exec passenger start", I suppose one of those words needs to be replaced with the name of the web app or?

Comment: I did attempt to simply comment out the authentication code posted above and restart the nginx, but that didn't work. That type of solution would be fine to me.

Comment: Capistrano is never installed on the production server. It is installed on the development machine, and you use `cap` commands to trigger actions on the staging/production servers, over SSH. This is all made very clear in the library [README](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano). (But maybe you don't *have* a development environment, since you "do not have access to git (???!!!)".)

Comment: `bundle exec passenger start` is a guess at what command you *may* be able to run, from the project folder on the production server. Unless you'd like to provide me with SSH credentials, or more detail on the passenger setup, I can only make vague guesses.

Comment: And restarting the `nginx` will not make any difference. `nginx` is only being used as a reverse proxy (e.g. to handle SSL certificates, TLS protocols and ciphers, potentially some rate limiting and filtering invalid requests, ...); you are not restarting the rails app by restarting nginx.

Comment: I attempted the "bundle exec passenger start", but it says bundle not installed. As for restarting nginx, I figured it was something like that. (Learning) Sorry, can't give out SSH, but happy to answer some questions to help you understand the setup more. 1 instance hosts the full RoR setup, so dev, at least not within our setup. As you pointed out the nginx restart wouldn't effect the .rb files, is there a restart command I can run within the app directory? Worth asking.